# Kubuntu 22.04: Ignore screen power state

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

Is there a way for Kubuntu 22.04 to ignore the power state of connected HDMI/DP Screens and keep them in the layout regardless of their power state?

When screens connected th DisplayPort or HDMI turn off, be it by the energy settings or their Powerbuttons the system recognizes the display as no longer being active, and removes it from the Screen Layout, thereby moving all windows to the remaining screen (which is connected via DVI, which does not have this characteristic, same as VGA), which is (at least for me) undesired behavior.